Need to retain a log4j2 logs on server up to 14 days
I need to retain a log4j logs up to 14 days on server. I am using log4j 2.17 library in my project.
I have added below properties in log4j2.properties.
status=error

name = PropertiesConfig

property.basePath=C:/logs
property.filename=C:/logs/app.log

filters=threshold

filter.threshold.type=ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level=debug

appenders=PR01
#appender.PR01=org.apache.log4j.core.appender.RollingAppender
appender.PR01.type=RollingFile
appender.PR01.name=RollingFile
appender.PR01.fileName=${filename}
appender.PR01.filePattern=C:/logs/app.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i
appender.PR01.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.PR01.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.PR01.policies.type=Policies
appender.PR01.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.PR01.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.PR01.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.PR01.strategy.max=10
appender.PR01.strategy.delete.type=Delete
appender.PR01.strategy.delete.basepath=${basePath}
appender.PR01.strategy.delete.maxDepth=1
appender.PR01.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type=IfLastModified
appender.PR01.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age=14D
appender.PR01.strategy.delete.PathConditions.type=IfFileName
appender.PR01.strategy.delete.PathConditions.glob=app.log\*

loggers=PR01

logger.PR01.name=com.java.logs.Log4j2Project
logger.PR01.level=debug
logger.PR01.additivity=false
logger.PR01.appenderRef.rolling.ref=RollingFile

After adding above properties on one lower environment just for testing I kept the age of 2 days when I checked the logs on 28/05/2024 then some log file (file count:6 till that time I checked) of 28/05/2024 I saw and 10 log files of 10MB of 27/05/2024 also able to saw but log files (app.log.2024-05-26.7, app.log.2024-05-26.6,app.log.2024-05-26.5) of 26/05/2024. Ideally it should show all 7 log files of 10MB of 26/05/2024 as per my understanding.
Also when I checked the logs afterwards like on 29/05/2024 then some log files of 29/05/2024, 10 log files of 10MB of 28/05/2024, 10 log files of 10MB of 27/05/2024 it was showing.
Why it was showing only last 3 log files of 26/05/2024 and all the 10 log files of 27/05/2024.

Why should there be 7 log files? You have configured strategy.max to 10. Are you sure no colleague has deleted the files without telling you?

There was 7 log files becoz less requests triggered. Yes I'm sure no one has deleted the log files. @siom Please help me to understand because this scenario I have seen yesterday as well

Can someone please help with the above query . It's really urgent.
